# Not able to resolve BigtableRow class

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I need to read data from Cloud Bigtable and write it out to Avro files. Upon searching Google, I found [`BigtableToAvro` converter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable/BigtableToAvro.java) which has logic to convert the mutation objects to generic Avro objects.

There is a class called `BigtableRow.class` in the logic and I'm not able to resolve in my code  and also not able  find what this class is.

Can any one please let me know if I need to add any external dependency for this `BigtableRow.class`?

Answer (score 3):

[BigtableRow is defined in the schema](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/resources/schema/avro/bigtable.avsc). Also, have you tried using the [Cloud Dataflow template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#cloudbigtabletoavrofile)?